# Why is this returning 0?

Tags: c#, rounding

Perhaps I have spent one too many nights up late, but I had the following code :

```
MessageBox.Show(
  Convert.ToInt32(
    Math.Round(
      (double)( ( i+1 )/r.Count )*100 ,
      0
    )
  ).ToString()
);
```

Which always returns 0, even when `i=120000` and `r.Count=150000`.  This is a simple progress calculation where `i` is the current iteration in the loop, and `r` is the collection ( List() ).

I have separated the code, and even the following still returns 0 :

```
Convert.ToInt32( 
           Math.Round( 
                      (double)(( 120000+1 )/167428 )*100
                      , 0 )
                )
```

Not sure whats going on here so any insight as to what I am doing wrong (probably a forehead slapper). It should be (using above numbers), returning 71.

@Habib's flag as duplicate :

> that duplicate you claim -- is actually different, even the
>   solutions don't apply here as this was a casting issue to double, and
>   not adding 'm' with additional decimal points to each variable in
>   play.

Comment: so what you guys are saying (reading answers below), is that I need to cast the integers both to double first, and that .NET doesn't do any magic when using mathematical operations (eg, float the number if divising two integers when needed)  ?

Comment: no just casting one will do, but do it before division not after.

Comment: @SanuelJackson It can't guess what you want, and in some cases integer division *is* what you want. So no, it doesn't do magic.

Comment: Got it.  Makes sense.   Adding a footnote, this wasn't as much of a forehead slapper as I thought it would be -- the math was technically correct, just the values weren't auto-converting to double.  Easy fix, but this is one of those moments I was expecting .NET to take care of more than it actually does :) .

Comment: lol.   love the downers tho. -.-  ... like why down-vote when the question is legit, and clear.   sometimes this boggles me as to why people down-vote easy questions (or difficult ones).  PS ---  that duplicate you claim Habib -- is actually different, even the solutions don't apply here as this was a casting issue to `double`, and not adding 'm' with additional decimal points to each variable in play.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will evaluate to ( 120000+1 )/167428 ) to 0 as they are int's and do not keep decimal precision, try this

```
Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(((double)(120000+1 ) / (double)167428 ) * 100))
```

Comment: sorry... have to wait 10 minutes to accept now ... o.0.  When did SO implement that ?

Answer (score 9):

Because `( 120000+1 )/167428` is still being done using integer math. Instead of ~0.716, it's 0.

If you want to avoid this in the future, make sure you're casting the numerator and denominator to a double as well.

```
( (double)( i+1 )/(double)r.Count )*100
```

Comment: The answer is right, but I think you meant `~0.716`. Either way it will still round to 0. I'm just OCD with math. :p

Comment: @DrewKennedy Sorry, finger slipped.

Answer (score 4):

You are casting to double *after* doing integer division.

Answer (score 2):

this is related to **implicit conversion**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx

the operation: `(120000+1)/167428` returns an integer as result, 0.
you are casting double after doing this integer division.

like other users suggest try casting the values:

```
  (double)(( (float)120000f+1 )/(float)167428f )*100
```

Comment: Really, referencing a java doc for a C# question?

Comment: Why not the concept is the same, probably your knowledge is only C# or .net technologies.

Comment: And? There has already been 5 other answers saying that. Misleading redirection is foul. But I see you at least fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: "hasta Lo que no se tragan les hace daño", ok so merg a chuparselas si  come rahat! :) thak you.

Comment: XD .. nice.  I upvoted for the research.  Also noticed you changed to MSDN link which is cool.  Just like to point out, if using  `f`, then don't need to cast using `(float)`.

Answer (score 0):

(( 120000+1 )/167428 ) will evaluate to 0

167428 does not go into 120001. what you can try is this:

```
Convert.ToInt32( 
       Math.Round( 
                  (((double)120000f+(double)1f )/(double)167428f )*(double)100f
                  , 0 )
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

If `r.Count` > `i+1`, then `(i+1) / r.Count` will give you a zero. Both are integers and so anything after the decimal point gets cut off.

You probably mean to cast either `i+1` or `r.Count` to double, then you'll get the answer you expect.

Eg:

`(i+1) / (double)r.Count`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You have to convert one of the two values to double before you divide.

```
Convert.ToInt32( 
           Math.Round( 
                      (((double)( 120000+1 ))/167428 )*100
                      , 0 )
                )
```